# how to Add seller Address on header in magento

Tags: pdf, header, footer

which file contain header and footer settings in magento for add and remove seller Address All seller show in my pdf i want only that seller which its product

Comment: Please avoid recreating the same questions everyday. Instead use the edit feature to add more information to your original question